# How to Decipher U.S. Passenger Manifest Text?

Tags: united-states, immigration, palaeography, manifest

Would love some help with deciphering the attached Passenger Manifest.  I can't make out the text in Line 14, Col 11 of the first image AND Line 14, Col 18 of the second image. The line in question (line 14) is for Andres Glavach.

[image: Passenger Mainfest Page 1]

[image: Passenger Manifest Page 2]

Answer (score 7):

You omitted links to the passenger list:
at ellisisland.org, the entry is indexed "[Andres Glavac](http://www.ellisisland.org/search/passRecord.asp?MID=20255620920057363584&pID=101756050197)"
at ancestry.com, the entry is indexed "[Andres Giavac](http://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?ti=0&indiv=try&db=nypl&h=4033989202)" (3 times!)

Column 11 (departure contact)
sister: Glavac Ana
Cze[rc?]socz Hung.
[image: Column 11 detail>]

Column 18 (destination contact)
br.i.l. [S?]obocan Martin
19[9?]. 201 Erie St. So Chicago Ill.
[image: Column 18 detail]

The placename in column 11 is recorded differently - as Cserenczocz - on line 15 (next line, Ivan Gabor, born in the same place) and in column 29 (birthplace).

[image: Column 11 & 29 place details]

Cserenczócz is listed in the "Genealogical Gazetteer of the Kingdom of Hungary" (Auslander, 2005) as being in Zala megye and was also known as Cserföld. Today it is called Črenšovci, Slovenia.